# Which Exchanges Allow Short Selling/Margin Trades with USD/BTC or USDT/BTC

Tags: exchanges, sell-bitcoins

I think `Bitfinex` did. But for example `Poloniex` has `USDT` & `BTC` but does not allow short selling with `USDT`.

Comment: PS: I found this so far: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Comparison_of_real-time_trading_exchanges

Answer (score 2):

There's apparently a website that reviews various exchanges that allow trading on margin:

http://margintradingbitcoin.com/

OKCoin and Bitstamp are the two that I've heard of on there.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to be complete. Also it is not stating if short can be done with `usd` or `tusd`. If I don't find a list I will iterate through the list of the bitcoin wiki and update that one.

Comment: Bitstamp doesn't allow trading on margin.